# Best way to update a Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a SP that updates rows in a table periodically (several times a day) the SP currently gets a feed of the PK and the update value. The input feed can contain 1 - 1000 rows.

I want to know if it would be better to change the SP so that it will only update one row at a time and have the application loop through the rows calling the SP for each row rather than just once for all rows.

Comment: Can you show the table structure, and a few examples of the calls the app would make / try to update? I'm trying to envision what exactly is being updated up to 1,000 times via a PK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without better specifics of the table and the calls the app is making, I'm going to assume that each call/value/row in the feed relates to a *different* PK. If they all relate to a single key value in a table where it is not the *unique* key (e.g. a child table, like `OrderDetails.OrderID`), the solution only changes slightly.

In either case, the application shouldn't be calling the stored procedure 1,000 times, for multiple reasons. Instead you can use a table-valued parameter and pass all 1,000 values in one shot.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TVP_TableName AS TABLE(PK int PRIMARY KEY, UpdateValue int);
```

The stored procedure takes this single parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TableName_Update
  @TVP dbo.TVP_TableName READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE t SET t.Value = tvp.UpdateValue
    FROM @TVP AS tvp
    INNER JOIN dbo.TableName AS t
    ON t.PK = tvp.PK;
END
```

Now your app can pass in, say, a DataTable of 1,000 items. (You'll have to figure this part out because you didn't mention what stack/language your app is in.)

Comment: that's perfect thanks, Out of curiosity. what are the multiple reasons for not calling the SP 1,000 times?

Comment: Because it's 1,000 different round trips, lots of extra chatter on the network, 1,000 different transaction log entries, and it's not transactionally consistent (imagine multiple users simultaneously calling the same procedure 1,000 times). It's similar to how we go to the grocery store in a single trip to get bread, milk, eggs, and meat, instead of going to the grocery store to get bread and then going to the grocery store to get milk and then going to the grocery store to get eggs and then going to the grocery store to get meat.